# Crystal Report :Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

Logon failed.
Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
Source: Provider
Description: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
Native Error:

Answer (score 0):

Basically your crystal report was unable to connect to the database. Normally you have to pass it server logon info or run it with a Windows account that has permission to the database

Answer (score -2):

Just unmark the option "Save Data with Report" under "File" Tab..